# Start typescript node server in terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to run this node app but it's in typeScript, [here](https://github.com/TutorialEdge/react-typescript-real-time-chat/tree/master/backend)

I have typeScript installed but how to I start the node server?

Comment: have you tried `npm start` command after doing `npm i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from the [package.json](https://github.com/TutorialEdge/react-typescript-real-time-chat/blob/master/backend/package.json), there is a watch command which is compiling the typescript files and then running the result on node. The command otherwise would have been: `tsc --watch & nodemon dist/app.js`

Comment: thanks but I have to install typescript globally first.